# how to position half an image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to add half an image just to the bottom of the screen.

**screen of how it should look**
[image: screen of how it should look]

**Image**
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `LayoutBuilder` to get `constraints` and [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for positioning image, maybe you like to have it as background image.

**Result**
[image]

**Code Snippet**

```dart
class HalfImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HalfImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              // because it is beyond width
              left: -constraints.maxWidth * .1,
              right: -constraints.maxWidth * .1,

              top: constraints.maxHeight * .7, // you may need to change value
              child: Image.asset(
                "images/WqyOC.png",
                // width: constraints.maxWidth * 1.2, // because it is beyond width
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
            ),

            ///* your rest widget with Positioned or [Align] widget
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```